# How can I fix the error "this launch file is invalid" when running a Dynamics GP macro?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dexterity, dynamics-gp

I've run a macro in Microsoft Dynamics GP for a few years.  Yesterday it ran fine.  Today it started showing the error "This launch file is invalid."  Neither the macro nor the Dynamics.set file have changed in years.  IT says there gave been no recent updates to GP.  I've tried the file on an installation on a local server and on my local PC and now get the same error.  I've found nothing online about this error when running a macro.  What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Here's the error:
[image]

Here's the macro (I removed the logins and passwords):

```
# DEXVERSION=14.00.0084.000 2 2
Logging file ':c:/MOGenerator/NFS_delete_mogenlog.txt'
CheckActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form Login window Login 
  TypeTo field 'User ID' , 'XXX'
  MoveTo field Password 
  TypeTo field Password , 'XXX'
  MoveTo field 'OK Button' 
  ClickHit field 'OK Button' 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form 'Switch Company' window 'Switch Company' 
  ClickHit field '(L) Company Names' item 3  # 'National Filter Sales' 
  MoveTo field 'OK Button' 
  ClickHit field 'OK Button' 
# User ID NFS_MOGen is already logged in to company National Filter Sales. Would you like to view your current logins?
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form DiaLog window DiaLog 
  ClickHit field OK 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form 'Switch Company' window 'Switch Company' 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form 'Switch Company' window UserActivity 
  MoveTo field 'Delete Button' 
  ClickHit field 'Delete Button' 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form 'Switch Company' window 'Switch Company' 
  ClickHit field 'OK Button' 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
# Your current copy of Mekorma Products Manager 14.00.0020 is incompatible. You need to upgrade to version 14.00.0155 or greater.
NewActiveWin dictionary 'Mekorma Products Manager'  form DiaLog window DiaLog 
  ClickHit field OK 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form syReminders window syReminders 
  MoveTo field '(L) btnClose' 
  ClickHit field '(L) btnClose' 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
ShellCommand 'Navigate to \cmdNavigationPane\ManufacturingButton\ManufacturingAreaPage' # Manufacturing
ClickHitIE , 'http://dexterity/product=7158/script=ExecuteAreaPageLink/args=7158,22009,22000/' # http://dexterity will be pre-pended
NewActiveWin dictionary 'MOGenerator'  form wMOGen window MOGen 
  MoveTo field '(L) pbImport' 
  ClickHit field '(L) pbImport' 
# Are you ready to run MOGen?
NewActiveWin dictionary 'MOGenerator'  form DiaLog window DiaLog 
  ClickHit field OK 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'MOGenerator'  form wMOGen window MOGen 
CloseWindow dictionary 'MOGenerator'  form wMOGen window MOGen 
NewActiveWin dictionary 'default'  form sheLL window sheLL 
  CommandExec form BuiLtin command cmdQuitApplication
```

Here's the Dynamics.set file:

```
25
0
Microsoft Dynamics GP
309
Fixed Assets
346
Manufacturing
414
Human Resources
949
FieldService
1042
Interfund Management
1235
Safe Pay
1428
Electronic Reconcile
1493
SmartList
1632
Cash Flow Management
1838
Technical Service Tools
1878
Excel-Based Budgeting
2277
Purchase Order Enhancements
2416
Control Account Management
2547
Enhanced Commitment Management
2992
CopierSeries
3104
Advanced Security
3180
Analytical Accounting
3278
Report Scheduler
3830
SmartList Builder
5597
HITB Report
6499
Dynamics Online Services
7156
Mekorma Products Manager
2404
Mekorma MICR
7158
MOGenerator
Windows
:F:GP2015/Dynamics.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/FORMS.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/REPORTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/fam.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/F309.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/R309.DIC
:F:GP2015/ICONMFG.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ICONFRMS.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ICONRPTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/HR.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/HRPFRMS.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/HRPRPTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/SrvcAdv.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/FRMS949.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/RPTS949.DIC
:F:GP2015/IFund.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/1042FORM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/1042RPTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/SFPAY.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/SPAYFRM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/SPAYRPT.DIC
:F:GP2015/AREC.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ARECFRM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ARECRPT.DIC
:F:GP2015/EXP1493.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/EXP1493F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/EXP1493R.DIC
:F:GP2015/CFM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/CFMFORM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/CFMRPTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/TAUTIL.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/F1838.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/R1838.DIC
:F:GP2015/XLBudget.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/XL1878F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/XL1878R.DIC
:F:GP2015/POE2277.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/POE2277F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/POE2277R.DIC
:F:GP2015/CAM2416.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/CAMFORM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/CAMRPTS.DIC
:F:GP2015/ECM2547.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ECM2547F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ECM2547R.DIC
:F:GP2015/QK2992.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/QDF2992.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/QKR2992.DIC
:F:GP2015/AdvSecur.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ADVS_FRM.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/ADVS_RPT.DIC
:F:GP2015/AA.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/AA3180F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/AA3180R.DIC
:F:GP2015/RPTSCHED.dic
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/F3278.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/R3278.DIC
:F:GP2015/SLBUILD.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/F3830.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/R3830.DIC
:F:GP2015/HTB5597.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/HTBF5597.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/HTBR5597.DIC
:F:GP2015/DO6499.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/DO6499F.DIC
:F:Dynshare/Main/Dictionaries/DO6499R.DIC
:F:GP2015/MEP7156.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/MEP7156F.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/MEP7156R.DIC
:F:GP2015/MICR.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/MICRFRM.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/MICRRPT.DIC
:F:GP2015/7158W.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/7158FRMS.DIC
:F:GP2015/Data/7158RPTS.DIC
```

Here's an example of running the macro:

[image]

Comment: Did you check in your EventViewer? Look in there under both Application and System section. Probably you will find more information regarding your problem. https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not running the macro from the dynamics GP folder, you need to specify the full path to the dynamics.set file and the macro file.

```
"F:\GP2015\dynamics.exe" "F:\GP2015\dynamics.set" "F:\MacroFolder\Test.mac"
```

Replace **F:\MacroFolder** with the path and folder where your Test.mac file resides

If your command prompt is in **F:\GP2015** folder instead of **C:\Users** and your macro is also in the F:\GP2015 folder then your command should work.